# Drilling through load bearing wall diagonally

Tags: electrical, wiring, framing, studs, load-bearing

I am familiar with the code requirements for drilling holes through studs in walls, whether they be loadbearing or non-loadbearing.
My question is, does it matter if the holes are drilled diagonally through the stud? The reason why I am asking is I need to drill a hole through a loadbearing stud and am planning on removing minimal drywall so that I wouldn’t be able to get a drill in the opening to drill a straight hole, only diagonally with a really long drill bit.
Also, does it matter if I have to drill through several 2x4s laminated together in a load bearing column?  Do the guidelines still apply as to the OK max hole size?

Comment: A diagonal hole will remove much more material (structure) than drilling a straight hole. Drilling through any stud without seeing what is on the other side (electric, plumbing, HVAC, etc.) is dangerous.

Comment: With drywall a little hole is about the same work as a bigger hole to repair, just use a bit more material(tape, mud, paint).